# ServiceStack Redis connection/timeout error handling c#

Tags: redis, servicestack

I am using Redis with ServiceStack and with a connection pool; now I know that the docs say that it can fail at any time (and it does randomly, especially when i'm ramping up connections; it has timeouts (especially on writes) all over the place while redis with the c & php(which is c) API does not suffer from that. I use the code from the service stack redis page but it does not really describe how to make it resilient etc.

Anyway; following stackoverflow & the docs, I have a connection pool but what to do if a call fails anyway? Do I just retry it until it succeeds? It all feels pretty brittle at the moment especially while I had this issue not at all when running big volume from the c api...

Note; we care about low latency for reads more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

The [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) client already has [built-in support for automatic retries](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#automatic-retries).

You can customize the [different timeouts on the Connection String](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-connection-strings) or on the [RedisConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisConfig.cs) configuration class.